# How to set username and password for basic auth in flask restx swagger?

Tags: python, flask, basic-authentication, flask-restplus, flask-restx

Im trying to add basic Authorization to my flask rest-x application.
By referring to https://github.com/python-restx/flask-restx/issues/271 I have made code changes.

But here there is no clarity on how to set and a username and password. As well in the swagger UI i see the login for basic auth happens with any username and password.

I have tried searching multiple resources but could not get a way how to set username & password and authenticate it. Please help regarding the same.

`Flask restx version: 0.5.1`

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
from flask_restx import Api
blueprint = Blueprint("api", __name__)
authorizations = {
    "Authorization": {
        "description": "Inputs: Basic \\email\\>",
        "type": "apiKey",
        "in": "header",
        "name": "Authorization",
    }
}

api = Api(
    blueprint,
    title="Dummy API",
    version="1.0",
    authorizations=authorizations,
    security="Authorization",
)
```

Comment: hi Hashr,
So how do I generate the keys themselves ?

Comment: Do you mean access token?

Comment: Yes, I didn't found anyway a description on how to generate them

Comment: You will need to create an authentication system using jwt or something like that... here's an example using pyjwt https://pastebin.com/Vyb2LCvz 

Tutorial: https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ https://aaronluna.dev/series/flask-api-tutorial/part-1/
Sample JWT keys: https://dinochiesa.github.io/jwt/